# How to prove that this sequence converges? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove this sequence converges: 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)}$

I noticed that this is continuous function which its derivative is always less than $0$ for $ x \gt 1 $, so I tried to do the integral test but with no success...

Some help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). We have that
$$
\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1{n\log^2 n}\le\int_2^\infty\frac1{x\log^2 x}\mathrm dx=\biggl[-\frac1{\log x}\biggr]_2^\infty=\frac1{\log 2}.
$$

Comment: Can you share how you calculated the integral?

Comment: @FigureItOut I used [Integral Calculator](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp).

Comment: The derivative of $\log(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$, and the derivative of $\frac{1}{u}$ is $-\frac{u'}{u²}$.

Answer (score 5):

Since the sequence $\dfrac{1}{n\ln^2 n}$ is decreasing, you can apply Cauchy's condensation test, which says that if $a_n$ is decreasing, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n <\infty \quad \text{if and only if}\quad \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k a_{2^k}<\infty.
$$
Typically, this test works well with series with logarithms, you will see why once you apply it.

Comment: thats a nice solution :)